# Get overlapping dates between two date ranges (in columns) - WITHOUT creating database objects

Tags: sql-server, date, t-sql, overlapping, adhoc-queries

I have a tricky situation in **Microsoft SQL Server 2016**, in which I need to get a list of dates that an employee was in Leave of Absence (LOA) in a PayPeriod, with fixed PeriodStart and fixed PeriodEnd columns.

See the figure below (the source dataset):

[image]

I have 4 employees in 5 rows of a dataset.

PeriodStart and PeriodEnd are fixed always, with the values Dec 15 and Dec 22 respectively (for 2020). I have each employee's LOA Start Date and LOA End Date in separate columns. The source dataset will have only one set of PeriodStart and PeriodEnd dates at any given time. Say, in the above case, it is ALWAYS Dec 15 and Dec 22. In someother cases, it will be Dec 22 and Dec 29. But only one range at a given time. The source dataset cannot contain Dec 15 - Dec 22 for Employee X, and Dec 22 - Dec 29 for Employee Y.

The desired output is as below:

[image]

The challenge here is, I am using our client's Query Builder, which **cannot** use **T-SQL** objects such as Temp tables (#), Table Variables (@), Common Table Expressions (CTE), User Defined Functions or even Views.

This is **purely ad-hoc reporting**, where you can ONLY create derived tables (or subqueries) and have an alias name and use it as a dataset. Such a dataset can be used in JOINs, and other regular stuff.

For example:

```
SELECT a, b

FROM

(SELECT t1.a, t2.b
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID) XYZ
```

The derived table (or sub query)    **XYZ**    is the main dataset for me.

I need my desired output to be aliased XYZ.

Can anyone help me achieve this?

Comment: To be honest, you're probably better of tagging this question with .Net, rather than tsql - since you've specifically said in your question that you're not able to directly write T-SQL statements

Comment: This is T-SQL coding only; sorry for the confusion; the Query Builder is made in .Net. I need a 100% T-SQL solution, without creating database objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  yourTable.EmployeeID,
  DATEADD(DAY, calendar.date_id, yourTable.PeriodStart)
FROM
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY the_primary_key) - 1 AS date_id    
  FROM
    any_big_enough_table
)
  AS calendar
INNER JOIN
  yourTable
    ON  calendar.date_id <= DATEDIFF(DAY, yourTable.PeriodStart, yourTable.PeriodEnd)
    AND calendar.date_id >= DATEDIFF(DAY, yourTable.PeriodStart, yourTable.LOAStartDate)
    AND calendar.date_id <= DATEDIFF(DAY, yourTable.PeriodStart, yourTable.LOAEndDate)
```

Please excuse typos, I'm on my phone.

Comment: Am not sure whether we can use System tables in the Query Builder. The Query Builder has a lot limitations.  Is it possible to remove the System Table ? I don't even use a table name (with schema) as dbo.X, but just as X.

Comment: You just need any table with more rows in it than you'll ever have days in between PeriodStart and PeriodEnd. But try it before you attempt to fix problems that may not exist.

Comment: ok, get it; in that case i will use some other table which has a large number of rows. thanks for the clarification

Comment: Great, thanks very much; it works with this dataset. Appreciate it. I will try in my client application, and hopefully once it is successful, I will mark your solution as answer.